# What is the probability someone is a positive given he or she tested positive?

Tags: probability

> A test has false alarm probability of $p$ and miss probability $q$, if the rate of true positives in the population is $r$, what is the probability someone is a positive given he or she tested positive?

If $t/f$ represents the result of the test and $T/F$ represents the actual positivity/negativity of the person. How exactly can I find the probability someone is a positive given he or she tested positive?

I see that $$P(t|F) = p, P(f|T)=q, P(t|T)=r, \text{ and } P(T) = P(T|f)P(f) + P(T|t)P(t)$$

I am trying to find $$P(T|t) = \frac{P(t|T)P(T)}{P(t)}$$

But I'm not seeing any way to find $P(T|t)$ explicitly.

Anyone have any ideas as to how to find this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that $p$ is a false-alarm rate we say that $1 - p$ is the probability the test is a true negative, and likewise $1 - q$ is the rate the test returns positive given that the individual has the condition. $r$ must mean that $100r$% of the population has the condition; I can't think of any other explanation for it (otherwise it would seem that $r$ and $q$ are redundant and we would have no way to describe what proportion of the population has the condition.) Thus, $1 - r$ is the probability of not having the condition.

So a simple application of Bayes' Theorem gives

$$P(\text{positive} | \text{has condition}) = \frac{(1 - q)r}{(1 - q)r + p(1 - r)}$$

Comment: So "the rate of true positives in the population is $r$" does not mean $P(t|T)=r$ but instead means $P(T)=r$?

Comment: Since then $P(f|T) = q$ and $P(t|T) = 1 - P(f|T) = 1 - p = r$?

Comment: The wording is strange but that must be what it is. Otherwise it's redundant with one of the other parameters and then what's the point? And when I read "miss" I interpret it as saying, "individual has condition but the test returns negative". Plus $r$ refers to a population rate, again justifying my suspicion.